# Appending to a cartodb table - duplicate key value violates unique key constraint

Tags: postgis, carto

I'm trying to insert rows from one `cartodb` table into another using the method outlined [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/145011/how-to-add-rows-from-a-dataset-to-another):

`INSERT INTO gfw_mining_test (the_geom, the_geom_webmercator, objectid, country,type, gfwid, st_area_sh, st_length_) SELECT the_geom, the_geom_webmercator, objectid, country, type, gfwid, st_area_sh, st_length_ FROM gab_mining_staging WHERE cartodb_id >= 0 and cartodb_id < 500000`

I'm getting an error that there's duplicate data in the table:

`duplicate key value violates unique constraint "gfw_mining_test_pkey"`

I've [queried the table to get the primary key](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Retrieve_primary_key_columns) and it seems to be cartodb_id. Both my source and my target datasets have this column. I'm trying to append data from my source without including the cartodb_id column in the hopes that the cartodb_id values for these new rows will be automatically generated in the target table.

Does this make sense? Why am I getting this error? Is there another key constraint that I'm running up against?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come across this issue as well, and have come up with a work-around which is as follows:

- Duplicate table
- Rename/Delete Original table (This will, of course, break any sharing this table had)
- Rename Duplicated table to have original table name
- Insert data to the Duplicated table

It seems like it might have to do with when the original table, and constraints, were created:
https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/issues/5612

Comment: Great. Thanks for your answer on this-- nice to have someone confirm the issues I'm experiencing. Will follow this approach from now on.